# Jquery: mouseover/mouseenter with delegate

Tags: jquery, delegates

I have this code:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

$('#trajectory-sequence').delegate('li:not(.disabled)','mouseenter mouseleave', function( event ) 
{
    if( event.type == 'mouseenter') 
        $(this).find("div:gt(0)").show();
    else if(event.type=='mouseleave')
        $(this).find("div:gt(0)").hide(); 
});
```

that shows/hides some children. Now, I would like to perform an action when the mouse is over of one of these children. I have this:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

$('#trajectory-sequence').delegate('li:not(.disabled) div:nth-child(4)','mouseover', 
function( ) {
    alert('mouseover');
});
```

But it seems that the mouseover event is never triggered. But when I use mouseenter instead of mouseover, it works perfectly, why?

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? `delegate()` has been delegated to the past, see http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 4):

The `mouseenter` event differs from `mouseover` in the way it handles event bubbling.

With `mouseover` event, if the mouse pointer is moved over the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The `mouseenter` event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So `mouseenter` works.